# Limits and Continuity: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: limits, continuity

Well, I'm doing this and I already find a resolution. I can write that limit as:
$e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}}$ and that results in $1$.

> My question is: Why can I do this?

Comment: If You know that e^x is continuous then you can do this. And the result is correct.

Comment: yes, but why can i do that? and why it have to be continuous?

Comment: Continuity is the property that lim f(x)=f(lim x).

Answer (score 4):

A function $f(x)$, is continuous at a point, $a$ if:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$$

This is the definition of continuity. So if $n\to \infty$, then $\frac1n \to 0$, so:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} e^{1/n}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} e^x=e^0=1$$

because $e^x$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score -5):

You can do it because when $n$ gets really big $ \frac{1}{n}$ is going to get really close to zero, and anything to the zeroth power is always one. $e^{0} = 1$. I'm not sure if that answers your question though.

Jeez, constant downvotes. Anyone care to tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Seriously, what's different about this answer compared to the top answer other than the fact that they stated the definition of continuity?

Comment: Because by your logic, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ should equal 1. Because "when $n$ gets really big, $1/n$ is going to get really close to 0" so the limit is $1^\infty$ which is *clearly* 1. "Stated the definition of continuity" is exactly the answer to this problem, not some "really big" "really small" arguments. The point is you can't make these hand-waving heuristic arguments as an answer. Maybe they provide intuition for basic limits, but for trickier problems, that is rarely the case.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... it was kind of a hand-waving argument. I figured the "really big" argument was an okay thing to do since there was only one instance of x in the expression, so in theory I wouldn't have to worry about how other parts of the expression change as x grows large, but that's pretty lazy and really just plain wrong. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Nitin I actually have one more quick question: Why does the domain of f(x) = x change when you multiply f(x) = x by x/x? Shouldn't it be the same function algebraically? Apparently not. What's going on here?

Comment: because $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$ aren't the same functions. They are when $x \neq 0$, but the latter isn't defined when $x = 0$ ($g(0) = \frac{0}{0}$ which is meaningless).